# Python equivalent of curl for posting data from file

Tags: python, curl

I am looking for a Python equivalent for the curl command below.

`curl http://localhost/x/y/update -H 'Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' --data-binary @filename.xml`

Incidentally, I normally post data as strings using the code below.

`curl http://localhost/x/y/update --data '<data>the data is here</data>' -H 'Content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8'`

```
baseurl = http://localhost/x/y
thedata = '<data>the data is here</data>'

headers = {"Content-type": "text/xml", "charset": "utf-8"}
thequery = urlparse.urljoin(baseurl, thedata, querycontext)
therequest = urllib2.Request(thequery, headers)
theresponse = urllib2.urlopen(therequest)
```

Comment: Why not just to use requests? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) its a great library for this kind of stuff. What you have there can be simply done by:

```
import requests

headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'}
response = requests.post(url, data="<data>the data is here</data>", headers=headers)
with open("filename.xml", "w") as fd:
    fd.write(response.text)
```

The problem of pycurl and some other url and http client libraries for python is that it requires more effort than the one you should need to achieve something relatively simple. [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) its way more user friendly and I think its what you are looking for on this problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: @andrefsp Thank you for this, however, I cannot seem to figure out exactly how to specify that my data is coming through from an external file. I am specifically working with something like this: `urlpath/update?commit=true&tr=x.xsl" -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" --data-binary @filename.xml`. How do I tell `requests` to post my payload (`{'commit':'true', 'tr':'x.xsl'}`) and the `--data-binary @filename.xml`?

Comment: @phiri What exactly do you want to post? {'commit':'true', 'tr':'x.xsl'} as a json object?
I'm not sure if I understood your question.

Comment: @andrefsp I am trying to post an XML encoded file (in this case filename.xml) to a Solr server for indexing. However, the `UpdateRequestHandler` API has other URL parameters (commit and tr). I basically need to know how to handle curl's `--data-binary` using the `requests` module.

Comment: @andrefsp Thank you very much. So wiring the `commit and tr` to the url ( `url = http://localhost:8983/solr/w5/update?commit=true&tr=x.xsl`) and then feeding the contents of file to data parameter of requests.post seems to work (`payload=open('file.xml','rb').read()`)

Comment: @andrefsp I was previously defining the other url parameters as part of the payload, which seems like the logical thing to do.

Comment: The question is about **sending** binary data and this answer does not give answer to this at all.

Comment: As @PiotrDobrogost suggests, the question is about __uploading__ a file, while the accepted answer was just __saving to file__! I've added below the correct code https://stackoverflow.com/a/55498926/5973334

Answer (score 2):

The question is about **uploading** a file, while the accepted answer was just **saving to file**!

Below the correct code:

```
import requests

 # Here you set the file you want to upload and it's content type 
files = {'upload_file': ('filename.xml', open('filename.xml','rb'), 'text/xml' }

headers = {} # Do not set content type here, let the library do its job

response = requests.post(url, 
              data="<data>the data is here</data>", 
              files=files,
              headers=headers)
fd = open("output-response.txt", "w")
fd.write(response.text)
fd.close()
```

The code above will read a file from `filename.xml` and upload it via POST, then it will also store to  `output-response.txt` the **response** received.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the python wrapper for curl called [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/)

It is really widely used so there are many examples of how to us the library on the internet.

If you are just getting started then it might be worth looking at [angry objects website](http://www.angryobjects.com/2011/10/15/http-with-python-pycurl-by-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Use beautiful python module called Requests
It can do 90% of curl options, plus it will work without compiling on Windows too.

https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests

It is super easy compared to curl, urrlib, urrlib2, or httplib, httplib2 ... :)